# Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.getHibernateExtension()" because "cc" is null

Tags: java, hibernate

I am making a hibernate project with cfg and hbm. But when trying to create the hbm I get this error in the console: An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.console.ConsoleConfiguration.getHibernateExtension()" because "cc" is null

I have been searching but didn't find any possible solution, Thanks in advance.